# How do I echo the name of a 'module' in my Laravel app?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

Currently I have different modules in my Laravel app

```
App
- Module
- Module 1
- Module 2
- Module 3
```

and I've grouped the routes for each module (for simplicity's sake).

```
// Module
Route::group(
    [
        'namespace' => 'Module',
        'prefix' => 'Module',
    ],
function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ModuleController@redirect');
    Route::get('home', 'ModuleController@index')->name('Module');
```

In the Views (blade templates) which have a title in the Navbar and I want the title to be the name of the Route group so no matter what page in the module I'm on, the module name is in the Navbar.

Currently I've tried putting

```
{{ Request::path() }} // which returns Module/PageName
```

in the blade template. As well as this

```
{{ Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix() }} // which returns /Module
```

But both of these have extra stuff in the output. The second one is the closest I've gotten I just need to remove the '/'

I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve this but if you have a better/more efficient way of doing this please let me know also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the solution is already in your code. you can use the first solution.
`{{ explode('/', Request::path())[0] }}` like this explode will divide the `String` into an `Array` each time that finds a `'/'` character. Then you can pick the first element of the `Array` that you know that contains the `Module` name.

Comment: Thanks this works well!

Comment: I will put it as a Answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution is already in your code. 
You can use the first solution. 
Just replace this:

```
{{ Request::path() }}
```

With this code:

```
{{ explode('/', Request::path())[0] }}
```

The method `explode` will divide the `Request::path()` into an `Array` each time that finds a `'/'` character. Then you pick the first element of the Array with `[0]` which contains the `Module` name that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the name for route and use `Route::currentRouteName()` to get the name of Route. Hope it help!